# I don't understand the X_train Y_train I/O in scikit learn?

Tags: csv

I have been attempting to use Scikit-neural network's mlp(multi layer perceptn) to train a model, for speaker recognition.

I have a csv file named 'mfcc_kushal.csv' that is arranged with 13 columns (for 13 features) and 1201 rows (for each frame). These are my own voice signal's features.

If i attempt to take this as ndarray, my X_train will have 1201 samples with 13 rows. Now my Y_train is basically a binary output, simply its me or not.
but there is an error saying the samples in X and Y are not the same.

The library tells me to use 1201 classes instead of two. Am i missing something. I think I am not getting the implementation.

## My code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from sknn.mlp import Classifier, Layer

def csv_extractor(csv_file):
    with open(csv_file,'r') as dest_f:
        data_iter = csv.reader(dest_f,
                               delimiter = ',')
        data = [data for data in data_iter]
    feat = np.asarray(data, dtype = None)
    feat = feat.astype(np.float)
return feat
feat = csv_extractor('mfcc_kushal.csv')
print(feat)
print(feat.shape[0])

#NN modeling
y_train = np.arange(2)
NN = Classifier(layers =[Layer("Sigmoid", units = 100), Layer("Softmax")],
                learning_rate = 0.001,
                n_iter = 500 )
NN.fit(feat,y_train)
```

The following output shows what it says. I have also printed the ndarray and number of rows in it. The ndarray are MFCCs of a single person for 1201 different frames of the same speech signal.

## Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also take the time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge).

Comment: Also, please add your output as text, instead of an image so other users can help you better

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: My question is? What am I doing wrong? What is it that I am not getting?